# Single image from multiple containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to create a single image from multiple docker containers?
Without using `docker-compose`

Comment: No, not directly. This sounds like an X-Y problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you @Henry, it may sounds like XY because i simplified an uread question. The point is this: i have 3 containers that i'd like to embed in a single app. I developed the single app based on this containers, but i don't want the user to run it as composed microservices architecture. I would like to simplify the deploying process to the user, creating a simple image with a singe `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. There is no concept like `one image` that covers all the services in the compose. Each and every service is going to have its own image.

But you can create a single docker image with all the services running inside the container. You need to configure all the services yourself in a single container. And there is also a docker-in-docker image and you can use that image to run your docker-compose file.

**`Docker in Docker`**

You can start the docker container that has docker installed with the following `bind mount` option

`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

And you can use the docker image which is a docker image that has docker installed and can start by:

`docker run -ti -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker`

And finally login to that docker container that you just started and can run some docker commands to verify.

You can do this with the `dind` (Docker in Docker) tag of the docker image, by:

`docker run --privileged -d docker:dind`

Below are some of the references:

[Reference 1](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind)   [Reference 2](https://itnext.io/docker-in-docker-521958d34efd)

Comment: Thank you @Ashok. One of the service is coded by another developer, so I can't create my container hosting his service since of the service i had only the image. Can i create a docker container that runs inside docker and take care of download the image, i mean to have a wrapper container, maybe running some ubuntu, who encapsulate docker services hiding them outside ?

Comment: Yes you can do it. Can upvote the answer if it's answered your question

Comment: Wow, i wouldn't expect. Can you explain me why or pointing to a working example or tutorial? I google a lot but didn't find anything

Comment: If you elaborate a bit about docker-in-docker image i will surely upvote and accept the answer!

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation i will upvote as soon as possible!